# How to convert integer data from database to string in php codeigniter

Tags: php, database, string, codeigniter, integer

In database ,The 'status' column includes values 1(Active users) and 0 (Deactive users), But in my view I would like to show this data as string "Active" and "Deactive". below is my code , the problem is it returns all users status "Deactive" in view. i would appreciate any help and guidance
Here is controller

```
 function index()
{
  $data['staff'] = $this->staff_model->getStaffDetails();
  $data['status'] =  $this->staff_model->getStatus();
//     print_r($data);  
// die;
   $this->load->view('admin/staff/index',$data);
}
```

Here is Model

```
 function getStatus()
{
 $query = $this->db->get_where('user_login',array('status' ))->result();
 return  $query;
 }
```

And here is the view

```
<tbody>
                    <?php
                     foreach($staff as $n)
                     {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $n->first_name;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $n->email;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $n->mobile_no;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $n->role;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $n->company_name;?></td>
                            <!-- <td><span class="icoact"></span> <?php echo $n->status;?></td> -->
                             <td><span class="icoact"></span> 
                             <?php 
                            //    foreach($status as $n)
                             {
                            if('status' == 1)
                             {
                             echo "Active";
                             }elseif('status' == 0)
                             {
                             echo "Deactive";
                            }
                             };?> 
                            </td> 
                            <td><a class="edit" href="<?php echo site_url('staff_edit/'.$n->id);?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>&nbsp
                             <a class="delete" href="<?php echo site_url ('staff_delete/'.$n->id);?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to Delete this Record?')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>&nbsp</td>
                        </tr>
                     <?php
                             }
                             ?>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: have your problem is solved or not??

Comment: Is **status** is the field in the same table where staff information is stored?

Comment: @mail2bapi yes same table , but if I use  <? php echo n->status;?> i get the value of 1 or 0,  so i created status object to convert integer to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in your view:-

```
<?php 

 {
if($n->status==1){
  echo $status = "Active users";
} else if($n->status==0){
  echo $status = "Deactive users";
}
 }?>
```

Comment: get message:Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I just removed foreach ($status as $n), and its solved my problem , thank you very much